# Elm implementing customTable data type

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am completely new to functional programming and I have an assignment to implement table data type. It is supposed to be represented as a triple:

```
("tableName",["key1","key2","key3"],["value1","value2","value3"])
```

All of the items are `strings`, the first is the name of the table followed by `two lists`, which are of the same length. For every key in the first list there is corresponding value in the second list. Keys can not be repeated, values can be repeated.

I should then implement multiple functions, for example:
- create new empty table
- insert (name, key, value)

Can anyone help me with how to implement this? I have tried multiple tutorials but none of them cover something like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a strict requirement that you need to implement it as a triple? IMO this is not the optimal way to design such a data structure. In case you are following some course or other instruction material then it makes sense. To get better answers to your question it's good to share what you have so far and specify what concerns you are facing. If you are totally lost (I understand that also), then here are some tips. 1) since in Elm you cannot store the state directly you need to pass the structure (i.e. state) in each function call 2) start with creating new table which inits the state.

Comment: @kaskelotti Thank you for your answer and tips. Yes, it is a strict requirement to implement it as a triple, as shown in the question. I am quite lost and completely new to Elm. I have just tried writing some small recursive functions and worked with lists, but nothing like this. And I am unable to find any helpful information online.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can start with the `type` definition -

```
type Table =
  Table (String, List(String), List(String))
```

Now we could create `myTable` -

```
myTable =
  Table ("foo", ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"])
```

To "implement" the data type means you would write the functions that act on the data type. Consider this extremely primitive `toStr` function -

```
toStr (Table (title, cols, rows)) =
  title
    ++ "|"
    ++ String.concat(cols) 
    ++ "|"
    ++ String.concat(rows)
```

```
toStr myTable
# foo|ab|cd
```

Perhaps you want `toHtml` -

```
toHtml (Table (title, cols, rows)) =
  let
    header =
      cols
        |> List.map(text >> List.singleton >> (th []))
        |> (tr [])

    body =
      rows
        |> List.map(text >> List.singleton >> (td []))
        |> (tr [])

  in
    table []
      [ thead [] [ header ]
      , tbody [] [ body ]
      ]
```

Which produces -

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hopefully this shows an important limitation of the current `Table` type requirement: It only supports one header row and one data row. Consider this alternate type -

```
type Table
  Table (String, List(String), List(List(String)))
```

If each data row is a `List(String)`, we could accept `List(List(String))` if we wanted more a list of rows. Or ...

```
type alias Datum =
  String

type alias Row =
  List(Datum)

type Table =
  Table (String, List(Datum), List(Row))
```

Adjusting `toStr` and `toHtml` to support `List(List(String))` is a good exercise for the reader.

Short of having your assignment, I don't know what else to add to your implementation. Maybe you could make a function that sorts the columns or rows? Maybe a function that filters out some rows based on a query? If you can provide more information, maybe I can help more.